# Impressão no lado do Client com C# MVC automaticamente

Tags: c#, mvc

Preciso realizar a impressão automaticamente de um arquivo PDF que esta em uma pasta no servidor, mas a impressão tem que ser em uma impressora especifica do lado do CLIENTE.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(caminho))
{
   string impressoraPadraoOriginal = new 
   System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings().PrinterName;
    try
    {
     myPrinters.SetDefaultPrinter("Nome da impressora");

        Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
             {
                 CreateNoWindow = true,
                 Verb = "print",
                 FileName = caminho,
             },
        };
        process.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        //Aguarda 5 segundos para alter a impresora padrão;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        myPrinters.SetDefaultPrinter(impressoraPadraoOriginal);
    }
}
```

Local funciona corretamente, mas quando vai para o servidor não funciona.

Comment: Possui algum código ? Poste ele que iremos ajuda-lo!

Comment: Não tem mágica... ele terá de ser baixado e exibido na tela do usuário para ser impresso... o que há são gambiarras com popup e iframe. Mas mesmo assim, a impressora que será utilizada é escolhida pelo usuário no momento da impressão

Comment: Pra que capturar a exceção para lança=la de novo? O que acha que ganha com isso? Na verdade tem perdas.